# How can duplicate processing of messages be avoided if two instances of same app subscribes to a topic?

Tags: java, duplicates, publish-subscribe

I have two instances of same application running and they both subscribe to same topic. Messages are  going to to published to both servers and both servers are going to process that same message. How can duplicate processing of messages be avoided if two instances of same app subscribes to a (same)topic using a stateless approach?

Comment: What kind of topic are you talking? Kafka only delivers messages to one consumer per topic. MQ queues also don't provide items twice when polled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topic has exactly opposite purpose from what you try to achieve. 
Queue stands for it.

If you still want to use topic you must have only one subscriber/listener on top of your application instances.

Then you have to force on your own any load balance algorithm between your application instances (e.g. round-robin or something more complex).

Comment: I must have two subscribers., incase one goes down. In this case there will be two events on the queue and both will be processed. how can i avoid processing of both

Comment: I did not get what scenarion you are talking about... If it is a Queue there is no scenario with "two events on the queue" if only one was published by publisher.  Still If it is a Topic all subscribers receive an event. Build very complex logic around "only one processing from topic" has no sense. Switching to Queue is a proper and simple way to go.

Comment: Thanks Vadmin, But is there a way I can tell/configure publisher that for subscription from either instance1  or instance2, publish the event on one single queue.

Comment: If you need to separate events use two queues, or there is an ability for subscriber to filter messages based on some attributes/headers or such (e.g. correlationId) If you really need to do that dig further about it. But from your question I understood that you just have two replicas of application and you do not care about which one will process message. If so you need to do nothing neither on publisher nor on subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are just a replication of each other, they should not have separate sources of data that they will listen to. The whole point of creating multi-instance architecture is to parallelize, and so speed up, processing of things. You should have a single source of data so that the once a message is taken in hand by one server it is not anymore available for the other, which can focus on following messages.

Comment: Thanks but mine is a publish -subscribe model. My apps subscribe to notifications . Since the apps are identical they are both going to process the same message and i want to avoid that

Comment: Ok, but you can publish your events to single container in the middleware, for instance it can be a rabbitmq queue. Since the queue is one, only one instance will be consuming a particular message.

Comment: I must have two subscribers., incase one goes down. In this case there will be two events on the queue and both will be processed.